# What is the `table` parameter in the UCSU ldHgGene tool?

Tags: format-conversion, sequence-annotation, ucsc, liftover

I want to lift over the annotation from *E. coli* release 29 to *E. coli* release 42. I have followed the steps for an annotation liftover mentioned [here](http://genomewiki.ucsc.edu/index.php/Minimal_Steps_For_LiftOver). I got the chain file for the final step and ran:

`liftOver -gff Escherichia_coli.GCA_000967155.1.gtf Chromosome.chain conversions.gtf unmapped.gtf`

However, I get the following warning:

```
WARNING: -gff is not recommended.
Use 'ldHgGene -out=<file.gp>' and then 'liftOver -genePred <file.gp>'
```

I would like to heed the warning. However, I don't know how to use the `ldHgGene` tool. Here is its help page:

```
ldHgGene - load database with gene predictions from a gff file.
usage:
     ldHgGene database table file(s).gff
options:
     -bin         Add bin column (now the default)
     -nobin       don't add binning (you probably don't want this)
     -exon=type   Sets type field for exons to specific value
     -oldTable    Don't overwrite what's already in table
     -noncoding   Forces whole prediction to be UTR
     -gtf         input is GTF, stop codon is not in CDS
     -predTab     input is already in genePredTab format
     -requireCDS  discard genes that don't have CDS annotation
     -out=gpfile  write output, in genePred format, instead of loading
                  table. Database is ignored.
     -genePredExt create a extended genePred, including frame
                  information and gene name
     -impliedStopAfterCds - implied stop codon in GFF/GTF after CDS
```

From what I understand, I am trying to give the liftOver tool the annotation in [GenePred format](http://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQformat.html#format9) instead of GTF format. So I need to convert the GTF format into a GenePred format and that's what the ldHgGene tool is for. So the command should be something like:

```
ldHgGene Escherichia_coli.GCA_000967155.1.gtf -out=Escherichia_coli.GCA_000967155.1.gp
```

but this returns nothing. The `-out` option does mean that the `database` parameter is not needed but the tool still seems to need the parameter `table`.

What is the `table` parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stumbled across this issue after getting the same warning message from `liftOver`. By using the `-out` option of `lgHgGene`, the `database` parameter is ignored but must still be provided. The `table` parameter should be the second column from your GTF file. Note that you must also specify the `-gtf` option (otherwise it expects GFF format). In my case, the GTF file looks like:

```
chr1    mm10_knownGene  exon    3073253 3074322 0.000000        +       .       gene_id "ENSMUST00000193812.1"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000193812.1";
chr1    mm10_knownGene  exon    3102016 3102125 0.000000        +       .       gene_id "ENSMUST00000082908.1"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000082908.1";
chr1    mm10_knownGene  exon    3206523 3207317 0.000000        -       .       gene_id "ENSMUST00000159265.1"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000159265.1";
chr1    mm10_knownGene  exon    3213439 3215632 0.000000        -       .       gene_id "ENSMUST00000159265.1"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000159265.1";
chr1    mm10_knownGene  exon    3205901 3207317 0.000000        -       .       gene_id "ENSMUST00000162897.1"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000162897.1";
chr1    mm10_knownGene  exon    3213609 3216344 0.000000        -       .       gene_id "ENSMUST00000162897.1"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000162897.1";
...
```

By default, `ldHgGene` outputs a leading 'bin' column which won't work with `liftOver`; this can be avoided with the `-nobin` option. So my command was:

```
ldHgGene -gtf -nobin -out=mm10.GENCODE_VM20.gp ignored mm10_knownGene mm10.GENCODE_VM20.gtf
```

The resulting genePred output can be fed directly into `liftOver -genePred`:

```
ENSMUST00000193812.1    chr1    +       3073252 3074322 3074322 3074322 1       3073252,        3074322,
ENSMUST00000082908.1    chr1    +       3102015 3102125 3102125 3102125 1       3102015,        3102125,
ENSMUST00000162897.1    chr1    -       3205900 3216344 3216344 3216344 2       3205900,3213608,        3207317,3216344,
ENSMUST00000159265.1    chr1    -       3206522 3215632 3215632 3215632 2       3206522,3213438,        3207317,3215632,
```